# Coding backpropagation in python

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I understand maths better than Python but I would like to progress in Python. It would be amazing if someone would like to talk about it with me.

I have a feedforward neuron network with only one neuron for the last layer and $l$ layer plus one input layer.

We would like to use stochastic gradient descent on the function 
$$
L(W,b) = \frac{1}{2M} \| \hat{y}(W,b,x) - y \|^{2}
$$

So we need to compute the gradient for the weight $W$ and the biais $b$. As
$$
\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial W_{j,i}^{k}} = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{i =1}^{n} {\langle \hat{y}(x_{i}) - y_{i} , \frac{\partial{\hat{y}}}{\partial W_{j,i}^{k}}(x_{i}) \rangle}
$$
with $W_{j,i}^{k}$ the $i$ th weight of the $j$ th neuron of the $k$ th layer. We only need to compute $\frac{\partial{\hat{y}}}{\partial W_{j,i}^{k}} = \sigma(z_{i}^{k-1}) \frac{\partial{\hat{y}}}{\partial z_{j}^{k}} $ with $z_{j}^{k} = \langle W_{j}^{k}, \sigma(z^{k-1}) \rangle + b_{j}^{k} $ the output of the $j$ th neuron of the $k$ th layer and $\sigma$ the activation function. This partial derivated can be computed by recursivity thanks to :
$$
\frac{\partial{\hat{y}}}{\partial z_{j}^{k}} = \sum_{s} { W_{s,j}^{k+1} \sigma'(z_{j}^{k}) \frac{\partial{\hat{y}}}{\partial z_{s}^{k+1}}  }
$$
with $s$ wandering along the $k+1$ th layer and $\frac{\partial{\hat{y}}}{\partial z_{j}^{l}} = \sigma'(z^{l}) $ so we can use a recursive algorithm.

Let's code our network :

```
class Network(object):


    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
```

So now we need to have acces to a vector $z$ containing the output. So I code (How to code it better ?) :

```
def output(self,a):
    res = []
    res.append(np.array(a))
    curlay = 0
    curneu = 0
    for s in self.sizes[1:]:
        z = np.zeros(s)
        for i in range(s):
            z[i] = np.dot(sigmoid(res[curlay]), self.weights[curneu][i]) + self.biases[curneu][i]
        curneu += 1
        res.append(z)
        curlay += 1
    return res
```

So now let's compute the gradient of $\hat{y}$. I think it could be cool to have a list of the partial gradient according $w^{k}$  [np.array $\big($ partial derivate according $w^{1}_{1,1}$,..., partial derivate according $w^{1}_{1,n}$ $\big)$, ..., np.array$\big($ partial derivate according $w^{l}_{1,1}$,..., partial derivate according $w^{l}_{l,p_{l}}$ $\big)$ ]

Now I'll stop coding a find a way to code it. 
First it's easy to get the partial derivated according to $W^{l}_{1,i}$ (only one neuron in the last layer) it's $ \sigma(z_{i}^{l-1}) \sigma'(z^{l})$. So now... how can I continue ?